# Order By on a sorted view should keep the view sorted column as secondary sort

Tags: mysql

I have a view:

create view cars as
select * from car order by name

Then i want to sort the view cars by type but it should be smart enough the keep the name as secondary sort column

Comment: A view is a derived table and as such is not guranteed sorted - apply your desired sorting criteria when you query it.

Comment: Thats not possible because the code doesnt know which sort columns the view has

Comment: Unfortunately if you query from the view and apply an `order by` clause, no other explicite ordering will be done unless you specify it, it sounds like you have a design flaw if you are relying on that concept.

Comment: Its a generic java class accepting parameters from the frontend. Problem is that the sort order from the frontend doesnt include the base views sort order because it doesnt know it. Therefor it needs to apply the sortorder coming from the frontend and still remember and apply the sortorder from the view